# Convert a list to a string without 'join'

Tags: python, string, list, function

I'm trying to create my own function that converts a list of characters into a string. I'm not  allowed to use 'join'. I need to use a loop to do this. I think I have the basis of it right, but I'm not really sure how to implement it into the function properly. I'm new to programming.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
def to_string(my_list):

    # This line will eventually be removed - used for development purposes only.
    print("In function to_string()")

    # Display letters in a single line 
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        print(my_list[i], end='') 

        # Separate current letter from the next letter 
        if i<(len(my_list))-1: 
            print(", ", end='')

    # Returns the result
    return ('List is:', my_list)
```

That returns the result I want (if the list is ['a', 'b', 'c'] it returns a, b, c). But there's a 'test file' we're meant to use to run the function which contains this code:

```
print("\nto_string Test")
string = list_function.to_string(str_list1)
print(string)
print(list_function.to_string(empty))
```

And it gives this result:

```
to_string Test
In function to_string()
r, i, n, g, i, n, g('List is:', ['r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'g'])
In function to_string()
('List is:', [])
```

Which seems to indicate that I messed up entirely, something to do with the 'print' function I think. Can anyone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You're not supposed to `print` the `string` form of the list, you need to `return` it.

Answer (score 5):

Your function **prints** your string to `stdout`, then returns the list itself unchanged.

Build a string and return that instead of printing:

```
def to_string(my_list):
    result = ''
    last = len(my_list) - 1
    for pos, elem in enumerate(my_list):
        result += str(elem)
        if pos != last:
            result += ', '
    return result
```

This loops over all elements, keeping a position counter with the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate); this way it's easy to detect if we are adding the last element to the result.

Comment: This is overly complicated.

Comment: @Scorpion_God: any manual string concatenation is overly complicated.

Comment: True, but there's no need to keep track of the position.

Comment: @Scorpion_God: I mirrored the OP's version, gave him a better tool than using a `range(len(my_list))` loop. We could have used slicing too, but *this is fine* for a coding exercise. Remember, this is a beginning student learning to code.

Comment: If this is a beginning student why did you use tuple unpacking and `enumerate()`?

Comment: I wouldn't be allowed to use 'enumerate' as we haven't been taught to use that function yet.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not a 'him', btw!

Comment: @user3611841: my apologies! I am normally very meticulous to keep my references gender neutral; I would have used *gave **them** a better tool*. I occasionally slip up.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use reduce function:

```
aList=['w','o','r','d']
aString=reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,aList)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to emulate the `.join()` method of strings than you may want to add a delimiter option to your function.

```
def to_string(my_list, delimiter):
    string = str(my_list.pop(0))
    while my_list:
        string += delimiter + str(my_list.pop(0))
    return string
```

`.pop(n)` will delete the nth element from the list and return it.

---

If you want to return the original list as well:

```
def to_string(my_list, delimiter):
    string = ''
    if my_list:
        string = my_list[0]
        for elem in my_list[1:]:
            string += delimiter + str(elem)
    return my_list, string
```

The syntax `my_list[n]` will get the nth element from the list. Note that the elements are numbered from 0, not from 1. The syntax `my_list[n:]` will return the elements of the list starting from n. Example:

```
>>> my_list = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'list']
>>> my_list[1:]
['is', 'a', 'list']
```

Comment: What if the original list should have been kept intact?

Comment: Now, why not use slicing for that second version? `for elem in my_list[1:]`? A `for` loop over `range()` *just* to produce an index is still not idiomatic Python.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Because then the function would fail with a one-element list and list slicing would have to be explained.

Comment: No, it won't fail for a one-element list. `['foo'][1:]` is an empty list, the `for` loop will simply not run. You already have to explain `list.pop()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, I did not realise that that was the behaviour of list slicing.

Comment: I don't think we're meant to be using delimiters (sorry, I don't know what that is) or pop or anything like that. We're supposed to use a for loop only, as I did in my example.

Comment: @user3611841 In your case the delimiter would be `, `. It is what goes between each element. If you don't know what something means, you can always google it. The second code example does not use pop.

Comment: @Scorpion_God Thanks very much, I did Google it, but the definitions went right over my head. Just assume I'm very stupid when dealing with me, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the list elements and add them to your string. (Just a simpler version of the proposed solutions)

```
def to_string(my_list):
  result_string = ''
  for element in my_list:
    result_string += element
  return result_string
```

To test:

```
a_list = ['r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'g']
print to_string(a_list) # prints ringing 

b_list = []
print to_string(b_list) # returns empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a unique way of doing it.

```
#Python print() has a unique ability

List = ['a','b','c']
print(*List,sep="")

#### Output ####
abc

# In this method I'm trying to using python's print() ability
# and redirecting the print() from standard output to a temporary variable
# and then using it.
from io import StringIO  # Python3
import sys


old_stdout = sys.stdout
result = StringIO()  #store everything that is sent to the standard output
sys.stdout = result



print(*List, sep = "")   #sends to variable result
#or do any fancy stuff here

sys.stdout = old_stdout  # Redirect again the std output to screen


result_string = result.getvalue().strip()  # strip() because it has \n at the end
print(result_string,type(result_string),len(result_string),sep="\n") 
#this actually prints(), and also the result_string variable has that value

#### Output #### 
abc
<class 'str'>
3
```

This will help you indetail. [Store standard output on a variable in Python](https://wrongsideofmemphis.com/2010/03/01/store-standard-output-on-a-variable-in-python/)